# How would you validate the resource owner if you have separate resource and auth server?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Given that I have an access token generated using password grant type from the auth server. Is it proper to store the userId inside the token so that when the resource server decrypts the token, it'll use the userId when querying to its own database to get, for example, all posts made by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : **yes** it is valid to have a self contained access token. Typically this will come in form of a [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). If this is the case, you can extract JWT's **sub** claim ([sub](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2)) to get end user identifier.

On the other hand, if you have a opaque access token, you can introspect the token from token introspection endpoint of identity server. The [response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.2) can have the optional subject (sub claim) which is the identity of end user.

Once you obtain user identifier either of way, it's up to your application to use it.